# Plotly python - plot positive and negative value with plotly but wrong yaxis

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I want to plot the revenue and the net profit of the company but the result is like this

[image]

The yaxis is strange.The yaxis should have base value at 0 and in 2017/6,2018/6 the orange bar should down not up, The y axis is random order.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qCJ7.png)

This is my code

```
def create_visual(filename):
    
    createDir_if_not_exist('out/y')
    createDir_if_not_exist('out/y/interactive')
    
    print('read file: ' ,filename)
    
    df = pd.read_csv('data/y/'+ filename)
    
    stockcode = filename[0:5]
    
    print('stockcode: ', stockcode)

    #print(df['Total Turnover'])
    #print(df['Net Profit'])
    
    fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])
  
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name='Revenue', x=df['Closing Date'], y=df['Total Turnover'],base = 0,textposition='auto'))
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name='Net Profit', x=df['Closing Date'], y=df['Net Profit'],base = 0,textposition='auto'))

    fig.update_layout(barmode='group',template="seaborn",
        title_text=str(df_stock[df_stock['StockCode'] == int(stockcode)]['Name of Securities'].values[0]) + '    ' + stockcode +'.HK',
        xaxis_title="date",
        title_font_color="red",
        yaxis_title=df['Unit'].values[0] +'    '+ df['Currency'].values[0],
        font=dict(
            size=18,
        ))
    #fig.show()
    pio.write_image(fig,'out/y/'+str(stockcode)+'.png', width=1480, height=780,format ='png')
    fig.write_html('out/y/interactive/'+str(stockcode)+'.html')
```

Comment: Pls share the data in text format in the question... at least a representative sample if the full data is too big

Comment: Is the cause of the y-axis value a string? Check with the data frame information. `df.info()`

Comment: I got it. The y-axis is a value string . Thank you